# Why does PHP always overwrite the same string in the JSON file?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to add a user to the json, but each time it overwrites the string, and it turns out that there's one user. I correctly described what each line does? But why is it being rewritten?

```
$ input = json_decode ($ _ POST ["phones"], true);
// that's what's in `input`-if that's what.
// $ input = '[["5345", "345345", "123"], "Michael", "Podlevskykh"]';

$ file = file_get_contents ('jsn.json'); // get the file
$ output = json_decode ($ file, TRUE); // decode
unset ($ file); // clean the variable

// then add to JSON
$ output = [
    'user2' => [
        'first_name' => $ input [1],
        'last_name' => $ input [2],
        'phones' => [
            'phone_1' => $ input [0] [0],
            'phone_2' => $ input [0] [1],
            'phone_3' => $ input [0] [2]
        ]
    ]
];

file_put_contents ('jsn.json', json_encode ($ output)); // convert to string
unset ($ output); // clean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the new array into `$output` using `$output[] = $new_data` or `array_push($output, $new_data)`. In your actual code, you are assigning the array with your new value, so you get only the last element.

```
$output[] = [
    'user2' => [
        'first_name' => $input[1],
        'last_name' => $input[2],
        'phones' => [
            'phone_1' => $input[0][0],
            'phone_2' => $input[0][1],
            'phone_3' => $input[0][2]
        ]
    ]
];
```